# Prestashop: How to regenerate manufacturers' logo

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-1.5

I have, in the directory `root/web/img/m`, several logos of manufacturers, in the shape of: `<manufacturer's ID>.jpg`.

My goal is to have each of these logos in the following shapes:

- `<manufacturer's ID>.jpg`
- `<manufacturer's ID>-logo_brand.jpg`
- `<manufacturer's ID>-m_scene_default.jpg`
- `<manufacturer's ID>-medium_default.jpg`

How could I generate the three latter shapes? Should I click on a button like "regenerate logos of Manufacturers"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope! You can't regenerate something that doesn't exist.

First go to Design->Images and add your new image types along with sizes and switch on for the brands,
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twG0V.png)

Of course the 100px width is just an example.

Only after adding them can you go and recreate the manufacturer images by selecting only those newly created.

Comment: You're welcome, Jars! I am not sure if you are aware of it but here you find the newest PS docs, https://devdocs.prestashop.com/. It may help you sometime.